# OFFSET FETCH in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, pagination

I have this query to paginate the results and it was working fine on SQL Server 2012. However I had to move my database to SQL Server 2008 and now my stored procedure is not working. I did some research and got to know that `OFFSET` does not work in SQL Server 2008. What alternative should I use now? How i achieve the same functionality with SQL Server 2008?

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_JobSearch]
    @EnteredKeyword nvarchar(200) = '', 
    @EnteredLocation nvarchar(200) = '',
    @PageNumber INT = 1,
    @PageSize   INT = 40
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        MasterJob.Title, MasterJob.CompanyName, 
        MasterJob.ShortDesc, MasterJob.Url,MasterJob.PostedTime, 
        MasterJob.Location, JobBoard.JobBoardName
    FROM 
        MasterJob 
    LEFT JOIN 
        JobBoard ON MasterJob.JobBoardId = JobBoard.JobBoardId
    WHERE 
        (MasterJob.Title LIKE '%' + @EnteredKeyword + '%')
        AND (MasterJob.Location LIKE '%' + @EnteredLocation + '%')
    ORDER BY 
        [MasterJobId] 
        OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
END
```

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a Common Table Expression (CTE):

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_JobSearch]

    @EnteredKeyword nvarchar(200) = '', 
    @EnteredLocation nvarchar(200) = '',
    @PageNumber INT = 1,
    @PageSize   INT = 40

    AS
    BEGIN

    WITH CTE AS
    (
      SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [MasterJobId] ) AS RowNum ,
        MasterJob.Title, MasterJob.CompanyName, MasterJob.ShortDesc,      
        MasterJob.Url,MasterJob.PostedTime, MasterJob.Location, JobBoard.JobBoardName  
      FROM MasterJob 
        LEFT JOIN JobBoard ON MasterJob.JobBoardId = JobBoard.JobBoardId
      WHERE 
      (MasterJob.Title LIKE '%' + @EnteredKeyword + '%')
      AND( MasterJob.Location LIKE '%' + @EnteredLocation + '%' )
    )
    SELECT 
      Title, CompanyName, ShortDesc, Url, PostedTime, Location, JobBoardName
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE 
      (RowNum > @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) )
      AND 
      (RowNum <= @PageSize * @PageNumber )
    Order By RowNum 

    END
```

Comment: Brilliant, Simply Brilliant!!! Exactly what I am looking for Thank you!